# What should I use for the list (20-30) items with different height?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have items which can have very different sizes. They can contain picture, or two.

I used ListBox inside ScrollViewer, scrolling was wery fast, but initialization was taking time.

I tried to use just ListBox or LongListSelector, I can't say it works: scrolling is very jumpy, some lags.

What can I use for this items to achieve fast enough initialization and smooth scrolling?

Comment: You don't need a ListBox in a ScrollViewer unless you have items besides the list that you need to scroll. THe list will scroll itself.

Comment: @WilliamMelani I use ListBox in ScrollViewer, because it has much faster and smoother scrolling. I have no problems with ListBox, when items have a fixed size. In this (question) case, items can be very different, some of them can be longer than screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inorder to overcome the black occurrence on scrolling you need to virtualize your scroll control. For that you should inherit IList and create a Collection of your own similar to ObservableCollection in which you will have to override the default indexer depending on your caching requirement and simultaneously maintain a cache for your items. I feel this might be what you are looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx

There is a sample project on that page. Try that out.

I also feel that you are facing this problem http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=258. I guess this will be solved using virtualization itself. For initialization, use lazy loading. Hope it helps